# Google Maps Javascript API with an OpenWeatherMap Tile Layer Overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openweathermap

How can I overlay an XYZ tile set ([something like this](http://openweathermap.org/help/tiles.html?opacity=0.8&l=precipitation)) on Google Maps API 3? I want to overlay weather data (cloud cover...etc). Feel free to use my OpenWeatherMaps URL to test it out:

```
http://maps.owm.io:8091/56ce0fcd4376d3010038aaa8/{z}/{x}/{y}?hash=5
```

I have spent multiple days trying to figure out this seemingly simple feature.
 If someone can provide a working example I would be in your debt. Feel free to check out my [GitHub Gist implementation using OL3 and OSM](https://gist.github.com/karlfloersch/1bb1e23ae7c31082cdd4) of this weather data overlay. I'd also love to know if this is not easily achievable/requires hacks.

Thank you!

**Update**: Thanks to @wf9a5m75's answer, I was able to put together this jsFiddle with the solution to my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/601oqwq2/4/

Comment: Let us know if @wf9a5m75 suggestion worked for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ImageMapType is for your purpose.
Read here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes

```
    var myMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
      getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return "http://maps.owm.io:8091/56ce0fcd4376d3010038aaa8/" + 
               zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + "?hash=5";
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    maxZoom: 9,
    minZoom: 0,
    name: 'mymaptype'
  });

  map.mapTypes.set('mymaptype', myMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('mymaptype');
```

---

**[update] Overlay the imageMapType above the current mapType**

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });

    var myMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
      getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return "http://maps.owm.io:8091/56ce0fcd4376d3010038aaa8/" + 
               zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + "?hash=5";
      },
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
      maxZoom: 9,
      minZoom: 0,
      name: 'mymaptype'
    });

    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, myMapType);
```

[image]

Comment: It seems it needs an opacity needs to be set. Also there is a missing comma after `minZoom: 0`. Here is a quick hacked together JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/601oqwq2/

Comment: In my solution, it looks like there are no Google Maps tiles under the OpenWeatherMap tiles. I tried deleting the map elements, but nothing is under. Do you have any suggestions/edits to my jsFiddle?

Comment: Let me confirm for clearly. Do you want to see the original google maps tiles under the OSM layer or not?

Comment: Yes I would like to see the original Google Maps tiles under the OSM layer.

Comment: Ok, got it. Hold on.

Comment: I updated my answer. The point is `map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, myMapType);`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @wf9a5m75!  I've updated my jsFiddle to include your changes, and it works exactly as intended.  https://jsfiddle.net/601oqwq2/4/

Answer (score 2):

Improving on wf9a5m75's answer.

The overlay image tiles don't cover the underlying map when zoomed out. We can make use of a normalization function (as mentioned in the link [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes)) to ensure they cover the whole area.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: 19.0356826,
          lng: 72.9112641
        },
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true
      });

      var myMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
          var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
          if (!normalizedCoord) {
            return null;
          }
          var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
          return "http://maps.owm.io:8091/56ce0fcd4376d3010038aaa8/" +
            zoom + "/" + normalizedCoord.x + "/" + (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + "?hash=5";
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        maxZoom: 8,
        minZoom: 0,
        name: 'mymaptype'
      });

      // Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
      // like the standard Google map tiles.
      function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
        var y = coord.y;
        var x = coord.x;

        // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
        // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
        var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

        // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
        if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
          return null;
        }

        // repeat across x-axis
        if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
          x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
        }

        return {
          x: x,
          y: y
        };
      }

      map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, myMapType);
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
```

[image: Results]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this accomplishes anymore (2018) - unless I'm misunderstanding - Currently, using `coord.x` and `y` instead of their normalized counterparts provides an accurate, moveable piece, that also repeats across the X axis, regardless of zoom. Additionally, OpenWeatherMap suggests using `https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/{layer}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid={api_key}` for free maps, which works practically the same, you just need to choose what kind of map you wish to overlay. (Precipitation, clouds, temp, etc)

Comment: Nevermind that last part - finally started understanding how Vane works, and the URL being using in your answer is the kind they still give! If anyone was as lost as me - You must make layers in the owm.io map editor, and select one or more of the weather layers.